# Reducing filesize of a jpg image by reducing its quality

Tags: php, gd

Is there any way in **PHP** to reduce quality of a **JPG** image in order to reduce its file size instead of resizing its dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this function's third argument:

http://php.net/imagejpeg

quality

> quality is optional, and ranges from 0 (worst quality, smaller file)
>   to 100 (best quality, biggest file). The default is the default IJG
>   quality value (about 75).

Comment: Is this works with compression?
I mean something like _setImageCompression()_ in **Imagick**?

Comment: From http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompressionquality.php Imagick::setCompressionQuality — Sets the object's default compression quality

So I think they are the same.